# How to automatically trigger an event by a particular date using Postgres and GraphQL?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm looking to create a booking system using GraphQL, Prisma, Postgres, and React that allows a user to rent a property from  date A to date B.  When the due date, B, arrives, I want the database to do two things:

1. Trigger an event updating its `Overdue` field from false to true when the due date is passed.  My current workaround solution is to have a query that fetches the due date, compares it to the current date and if the current date is passed the due date, mutate the `Overdue` field from false to true.  But, the problem with this solution is that it only works when the query is performed, which means the user has to necessarily visit the website.
2. This second thing is tied into the first one, but how do I send a proactive alert from the database to the user with email notifying the overdue date?

Answer (score 0):

I fear I am too late with the response. However, this can still be helpful to you or others:

Triggering events immediately are simple and straight forward. You can use postgres triggers to do that. However, scheduling an event trigger for future (in your case dateB) is something you can do only with an advanced event queue.

As far as I know, this won't be possible with Prisma. You will have to integrate with some other eventing queue.

However, if you want to simplify things, you can use Space Cloud (open source tool similar to Prisma) - https://github.com/spaceuptech/space-cloud. It supports postgresql and graphql. Also Space Cloud has an inbuilt eventing queue by which you can trigger your custom logic at a scheduled future time as well!!

PS: I am the co-founder of Space Cloud. You can join our discord server -  https://discordapp.com/invite/ypXEEBr if you want any help!